# Button element in array with onClick property to change state the specific button that is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array of button that is rendered using .map to print out the rows in data table. Each row have button that trigger the Edit panel popup. The problem that I currently have is when one button is clicked, the Edit panel on all rows.

The code:

```
          const [showEdit, setShowEdit] = useState([]);

          <tbody>
            {appSettingsList.map((appSettings, i) => (
              <tr key={i}>
                <td>{appSettings.Name}</td>
                <td>{appSettings.BackgroundColor}</td>
                <td>{appSettings.FontSize}</td>
                <td>{appSettings.FontFamily}</td>
                <td>{appSettings.Theme}</td>
                <td>{appSettings.NavigationBar}</td>
                <td className="action-column">
                  <button
                    key={i}
                    className="button-green"
                    onClick={() => setShowEdit(!showEdit)}
                  >
                    Edit
                  </button>
                </td>
                <td>{showEdit ? <EditApplicationSettings /> : null}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
```

How can I make that each button have different state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the edit logic for each row independently.

1. Create a `TableRow` component with toggling Edit View logic.

```
const TableRow = ({ appSettings, i }) => {
    const [showEdit, setShowEdit] = useState([]);

    return (
        <tr key={i}>
            <td>{appSettings.Name}</td>
            <td>{appSettings.BackgroundColor}</td>
            <td>{appSettings.FontSize}</td>
            <td>{appSettings.FontFamily}</td>
            <td>{appSettings.Theme}</td>
            <td>{appSettings.NavigationBar}</td>
            <td className="action-column">
                <button
                    key={i}
                    className="button-green"
                    onClick={() => setShowEdit(!showEdit)}
                >
                    Edit
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>{showEdit ? <EditApplicationSettings /> : null}</td>
        </tr>
    );
};
```

2. Iterate over `TableRow` elements.

```
<tbody>
    {appSettingsList.map((appSettings, i) => (
        <TableRow appSettings={appSettings} i={i} />
    ))}
</tbody>
```

Comment: @alep, let me know if you have any issues with this solution

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have tested it and it works. Is separating the rows to another component is better code management than the one suggest by @iamhyunq?

Answer (score 3):

Your state should be index of active row

```
      const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(null);

      <tbody>
        {appSettingsList.map((appSettings, i) => (
          <tr key={i}>
            <td>{appSettings.Name}</td>
            <td>{appSettings.BackgroundColor}</td>
            <td>{appSettings.FontSize}</td>
            <td>{appSettings.FontFamily}</td>
            <td>{appSettings.Theme}</td>
            <td>{appSettings.NavigationBar}</td>
            <td className="action-column">
              <button
                key={i}
                className="button-green"
                onClick={() => setActiveIndex(i)}
              >
                Edit
              </button>
            </td>
            <td>{activeIndex === i ? ( <button key={i} className="button-green" onClick={() => setActiveIndex(null)} > Edit </button> ) : ( <button key={i} className="button-green" onClick={() => setActiveIndex(i)} > Edit </button> )}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tested it and the onclick does not trigger all rows now. However, by using this method, the state cannot be reverse back by the same onclick event. So i made some changes.

Comment: {activeIndex === i ? (
     <button
                key={i}
                          className="button-green"
                          onClick={() => setActiveIndex(!i)}
                        >
                          Edit
                        </button>
                      ) : (
                        <button
                          key={i}
                          className="button-green"
                          onClick={() => setActiveIndex(i)}
                        >
                          Edit
                        </button>
  )}